# Using Excel VBA workout next value in a Alpha Numeric numbering system

Tags: excel, vba

Ok this is the style of the numbering system I have

```
A0
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
A7
A8
A9
AA
AB
AC
AD
....
B0
B1
B2
B3
B4
B5
B6
B7
B8
B9
BA
BB
BC
....
C0
C1
etc
```

I need a function where I could pass in **C9** and it returns **CA**

To clarify, the rules are like this

A0-> A9 then
AA -> AZ
B0 -> B9
BA -> BZ

So the second letter follows this sequency

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

After that the first digit increases using the same sequence

Comment: I am sorry but your question is not clear to me.

Comment: let me try and clarify

Comment: you mean like if `A9` then return `AA` or `BB`  if `BA`?

Comment: Why VBA then and not a formula?

Comment: I'm using vba to control a remote application via an readonly sheet, so I need a self contained forumla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? The logic is to get the `ASC` of the digit and increment it by one (conditions apply)

```
Sub sample()
    Dim sCheck As String

    '~~> Uncomment any of the below to test
    'sCheck = "AZ"
    'sCheck = "B9"
    'sCheck = "ZZ"
    'sCheck = "C9"

    Debug.Print GetNext(sCheck)
End Sub

Function GetNext(s As String) As String
    If s = "" Then Exit Function

    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String

    s1 = Left(s, 1)
    s2 = Right(s, 1)

    Select Case UCase(s2)

    Case "Z"
        If s1 = "Z" Then
            GetNext = "You have reached the end of the sequence"
            Exit Function
        End If

        s1 = Chr(Asc(s1) + 1)
        s2 = "0"
    Case "9"
        s2 = "A"
    Case Else
        s2 = Chr(Asc(s2) + 1)
    End Select

    GetNext = s1 & s2
End Function
```

Comment: Is this assuming I have to write the desired sequence in the sheet? Because I can't do that

Comment: Where is the sequence stored otherwise?

Comment: Also what comes after `AZ` or `BZ`... Esp after `ZZ`?

Comment: ZZ is the last in the sequence.

Comment: Thanks. Entering A0 gives me AB it should give me A1

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: This fails on `9Z` (returns `:0`) - needs another condition under the first `Case "Z"`

Comment: @chrisneilsen: Not only that. It doesn't cover many cases. For example "1234". The above code will work only if you specify something from the above list. `9Z` is not a part of the list. I am sure OP can put all the relevant checks that are required in case required.

Comment: @Sid maybe I read too much into the OP, I thought he wanted to handle all 2 character cases

Comment: @chrisneilsen: No only from the list which starts from `A0to ZZ` So the first letter will always be an alphabet.